# How to run Signal Desktop in the background?

Tags: startup-applications, system-tray, instant-messaging

How is it possible to run Signal Desktop in the background on Ubuntu with a little icon in the taskbar at the top of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line or as Startup Application:

```
signal-desktop --start-in-tray --no-sandbox
```

`--no-sandbox` is needed because the Debian package does not install the sandbox helper as SUID. It is taken directly from the .desktop file, i.e. Signal is run with that option when you start it normally from the launcher in your DE.

`--start-in-tray` instead of `--use-tray-icon` because the latter option opens the main window at startup.

It's going to use the same amount of RAM minimised to the tray as it would with the main window open, though. It's just for tidying up your active windows.
Source: [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/signal/comments/m0p29a/how_to_run_signal_desktop_in_the_background_on/gq9o1wb?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: That `.` by the end is a mistake, is it?